# Detect changes to playlist with Youtube Playlist API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, youtube-api

Is it possible to detect the change to a user's video playlists and fire an event  using the YouTube API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a press-one-button solution here. But you can try using [PlaylistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#top_of_page). It returns the videos contained in the playlist (50 maxresult per set). So if you want to detect if there's any changes, parse the current list and compare it to the original items contained in the list.

Comment: OK thanks, any suggestions on attaching an event to it or am i left to polling afer a preset interval